# Use environment "username" in Task Scheduler 'actions' path

Tags: excel, scheduled-tasks

I have a Task Scheduler entry whose "add Arguments" action field contains "C:\Users<my user name>\Desktop\MyFile.xlsm"
Is there a syntax that will allow me to use the environment variable %username% (batch) / environ("username") (VBA) etc so the task will pick up the user acct for the local machine?
Caveat: I REALLY prefer to not need each user installing a PS/Batch/Shell/VB script file.
But beggars can't be choosers.

I tried numerous iterations of quotes, double quotes, no quotes, broken quotes, @ signs, <> symbols, and $. All threw syntax errors (actually, "couldn't find" errors).

Comment: this might help https://superuser.com/questions/270643/how-to-pass-an-argument-to-a-windows-scheduled-task-with-spaces-in-it

Comment: Thanks Bart. I appreciate your time and response. It appears I was blinded by the forest, and the 'tree' was obvious (at least in my morning testing. "C:\Users\%username%\blah\blah"
appears to be working. Guess I was blinded by the 'quotes within strings' fiasco that VBA presents. The solution was exactly what I should've guessed. Thanks again.